# How do I create a logo to represent a file of text?

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, responsive-design, graphical-logo

how do I build a logo to tell the user they are going to click on a video or a text or a quiz like this?

[image]

how do I build that star and video click button and that text file logo?

THANKS

Comment: Do you need to build them yourself? If not there are icon libraries out there (e.g. fontawesome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find various sites that have free logos, I like https://www.iconfinder.com/ it has free downloadable PNG's

If you want the logo's to be clickable I would have a button in the HTML and wrap the image inside the element like so:

`<button> <img src="./image.png" /> </button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a svg using a `<svg>` tag. You can make your own drawing! Here's how to.

## Get Started with SVG

In your svg tag, first make two attributes called width and height and these will be your svg dimensions.

```html
<h1>A SVG!(Blank)</h1>
<svg width="200" h>

</svg>
```

## A Path

A path is what you normally think of. A path to a city. A path to a mountain. use the path tag to make your drawings.

## Commands

All of the commands are stored in the `d` attribute.

- M = moveto
- L = lineto
- H = horizontal lineto
- V = vertical lineto
- C = curveto
- S = smooth curveto
- Q = quadratic Bézier curve
- T = smooth quadratic Bézier curveto
- A = elliptical Arc
- Z = closepath

Here's how to use all of them:

```html
<h1>SVG Shapes!</h1>
<h2>Square</h2>
<svg width="100" height="100">
        <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L100 100 L0 100 Z">Sorry, but your browser doesn't support inline SVG.</path>
    </svg>
```

You can use more than one path in a SVG.

## Colors!

Use the attribute `fill` in the path tag to change the color using rgb or rgba color.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you would want to use fontawesome to get icons. to get it you must do in the `<head>` tag with
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0-beta1/css/all.css">`
once you implemented that into your code, go to https://fontawesome.com/ and search which icon you want. once you have use the `<i>` tag to get icon's.
After you have chosen and decided what you want you can start with javascript
and the html `<button>` tag. So let me give you an example on the html
`<button onclick="cheese()"><i class="fa-thin fa-star">Click</i></button>` now you can add that anywhere on your html page. now with js.

```
<script>
function cheese() {
window.open('https://google.com');
}
</script>
```